# laravel　npm run production Compiled successfully，but npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack

```
npm run dev
```

was successful.

```
npm run prod
```

was unsuccessful with:

> ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm log message after `npm run prod`:

```
DONE  Compiled successfully in 91052ms                                                                                                                                                     8:46:32 AM

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-13T08_46_33_901Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ prod: `npm run production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-13T08_46_33_920Z-debug.log


To maintain team`s package version consistency,package version is fixed in package-lock.json.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Check your log file here **/root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-13T08_46_33_901Z-debug.log**

Answer (score 1):

You could try to clear the npm cache and by deleting the node_module folder.

Remove npm Cache

```
$ npm cache clean --force
```

Delete node_modules by

```
$ rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

Or delete it manually.

And then run

```
$ npm install
```

Comment: thanks your answer，To maintain team`s package version consistency,package version is fixed in package-lock.json.